# Suddenly throw ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'importlib.util'

Tags: python-3.7

I was trying to install some python packages. Before I was not having this issue. it suddenly started giving me `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'importlib.util'` error.
Full log is below

```
#8 53.71 Collecting packaging
#8 53.74   Downloading packaging-20.9-py2.py3-none-any.whl (40 kB)
#8 53.84 Collecting importlib<2.0.0,>=1.0.4
#8 53.87   Downloading importlib-1.0.4.zip (7.1 kB)
#8 53.91     ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
#8 53.91      command: /usr/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-0ljeewgl/importlib/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-0ljeewgl/importlib/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-nx4pttf0
#8 53.91          cwd: /tmp/pip-install-0ljeewgl/importlib/
#8 53.91     Complete output (11 lines):
#8 53.91     Traceback (most recent call last):
#8 53.91       File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
#8 53.91       File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
#8 53.91         import distutils.core
#8 53.91       File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/core.py", line 16, in <module>
#8 53.91         from distutils.dist import Distribution
#8 53.91       File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/dist.py", line 19, in <module>
#8 53.91         from distutils.util import check_environ, strtobool, rfc822_escape
#8 53.91       File "/usr/lib/python3.7/distutils/util.py", line 9, in <module>
#8 53.91         import importlib.util
#8 53.91     ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'importlib.util'
#8 53.91     ----------------------------------------
#8 53.91 ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
------
```

Comment: Could you fix it? Any updates, I am new to python, I am facing the same issue.

Comment: No, just downgrade python version and installed all other internal packages without dependency.